# Adding values to custom (DataExt) fields when adding line items to existing quickbooks Estimates

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

I'm trying to find the best way to add a value to a DataExt field when adding a line item to an existing Quickbooks transaction (in this particular case an Estimate).  I can add a value for a DataExt field when adding line items to a *NEW* Estimate since the IEstimateLineAdd object includes IDataListExt.   However,  IEstimateLineMod does not appear to include IDataExtList. There also does not appear to be support for defMacro/useMacro either.   I would like to avoid having to go back and dig out the line items (using some combination of their data values) from the Response data, get the TxnLineIDs for each one and then use DataExMod to add the custom data field after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, IEstimateLineMod does not appear to include IDataExtList.

Correct.

> There also does not appear to be support for defMacro/useMacro either.

Also correct.

> I would like to avoid having to go back and dig out the line items (using some combination of their data values) from the Response data, get the TxnLineIDs for each one and then use DataExMod to add the custom data field after the fact.

That is exactly what you need to do.